# setRetainInstance(true) with Activity in the Background

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

if I have an `Activity` which hosts a Fragment with `setRetainInstance(true)` what will happen if this Activity is killed when it is in the background i.e another `Activity` is in the top of it . does the `Fragment` get destroyed also when the Activity is killed ????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes All Activity retained Fragment will be destroyed , retain feature helps you retain Fragment object only for configuration change like Activity rotation ,not when the os kills the Activity when it  needs to reclaim memory .